# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I'm creating a REST API using Jersey. On my local machine, I was running Apache Tomcat 8 with maven. When I run my eclipse on my local machine, it works fine. However, when I tried to build via Jenkins on my remote server (I'm pushing my changes to the remote server and let it build there), I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

I've searched online and it says it has something to do with Jerser v1 and v2 conflicting with each other. My local machine and remote machine has the same source code, same JDKs but when deployed, the remote machine throws that error when the endpoint is hit. What might go wrong

Comment: This error means that the code was compiled against a version of Jersey which does have this method, but then you're trying to run it with an obsolete version of Jersey. Look through the Tomcat directory on the remote machine - is there a rogue jar hiding somewhere?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you're not specifying the version for two of your dependencies. I'm not even sure how your project is compiling - I thought this would result in a Maven error.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Project is compiling because the OP is importing `jersey-bom` with `<scope>import</scope>`. The versions are defined there. But it seems the OP is redefining `jersey-client` version so there must be a problem here.

Comment: Jersey client is 1.X whereas the rest is 2.X? I would assume that can't work...and this is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was mixing Jersey 1 and 2. Removed the old jersey 1 code and used the jersey2 implementation and was fixed (as per the comments above).